# onContextItemSelected to Dialog

Tags: java, android

I get this error when i am selecting a ContextMenu Item to pop up a custom Dialog.

```
 W/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44f518c0
```

Code below

```
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    Map<String, String> data = (Map<String, String>) getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String user_ids = preferences.getString("userID", null);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.pm:
        pms(data.get("pid"),user_ids,data.get("Name"));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
  }

private void pms(final String fu2, final String to,final String to2) {
    dialog = new Dialog(this.getParent());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_reply);
    dialog.setTitle("To: "+to2);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    body = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    sub = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    Button button2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            new ADownloadFileAsync().execute(fu2);
        }
        });
    dialog.show();
}
```

I am only assuming that the Contextmenu is not out of focus before it calls the dialg. Because I can call the dialog from a button just fine.

Comment: This isn't an error. It's just a warning. I see them all the time in my apps. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Oh, you never said that. Let me take a closer look.

Comment: Ok Kurtis don't shoot me, but I forgot to change my case R.id.pm: to case 1: Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that jumps out at me is the use of the parent context as opposed to the calling activity context when you create the dialog.

```
dialog = new Dialog(this.getParent());
```

Are you sure it doesn't need to just be

```
dialog = new Dialog(this);
```

None of the examples I've seen so far involve the use of calling the current parent in the constructor.

Also check out the Creating a Custom Dialog section here  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

and the related bit on Showing a Dialog http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the better solution would be to just move to the [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). Even if you're developing on and older api, you can access it through the [android compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).